# Crash log from Apple review

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

i need help here with a crash log from Apple´s Review Team. I tested the app on OS X Lion and Mountain Lion without problems, now i must find where the problem could be. The Thread 5 indicate a crash, maybe something with com.apple.CFNetwork but i can´t figure when i call him. many regards, Nahuel.

```
Process:         Commit [7829]
Path:            /Applications/Commit.app/Contents/MacOS/Commit
Identifier:      ar.com.adband.Commit
Version:         1.0 (1)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [148]
User ID:         201

Date/Time:       2013-06-11 12:48:19.010 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.4 (12E55)
Report Version:  10

Crashed Thread:  5

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: EXC_I386_GPFLT

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: release

+ Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff855ca686 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff855c9c42 mach_msg + 70
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87583233 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87588916 __CFRunLoopRun + 1078
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff875880e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8b615eb4 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 209
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8b615c52 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 356
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8b615ae3 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8305d533 _DPSNextEvent + 685
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8305cdf2 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff830541a3 -[NSApplication run] + 517
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82ff8bd6 NSApplicationMain + 869
12  ar.com.adband.Commit            0x00000001027a7154 0x1027a5000 + 8532

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff855cc6d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c80af4c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c80ad13 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c7f51d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff855ccd16 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff82144dea _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 883
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff821449ee _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff855ca686 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff855c9c42 mach_msg + 70
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87583233 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87588916 __CFRunLoopRun + 1078
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff875880e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87596dd1 CFRunLoopRun + 97
6   ar.com.adband.Commit            0x00000001027c20a5 0x1027a5000 + 118949
7   ar.com.adband.Commit            0x00000001027c2af3 0x1027a5000 + 121587
8   ar.com.adband.Commit            0x00000001027ae657 0x1027a5000 + 38487
9   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8785d562 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c8087a2 _pthread_start + 327
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c7f51e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff855cc322 __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff875c7f46 __CFSocketManager + 1302
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c8087a2 _pthread_start + 327
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c7f51e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff82aa6750 objc_msgSend_vtable14 + 16
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8755c28a CFRelease + 170
2   com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff8ce82f43 SocketStreamSignalHolder::~SocketStreamSignalHolder() + 23
3   com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff8ce82062 SocketStream::socketCallback(__CFSocket*, unsigned long, __CFData const*, void const*) + 198
4   com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff8ce81f81 SocketStream::_SocketCallBack_stream(__CFSocket*, unsigned long, __CFData const*, void const*, void*) + 83
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff875a4fa5 __CFSocketPerformV0 + 1045
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87565b31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87565455 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 245
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff875887f5 __CFRunLoopRun + 789
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff875880e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87596dd1 CFRunLoopRun + 97
11  ar.com.adband.Commit            0x00000001027c20a5 0x1027a5000 + 118949
12  ar.com.adband.Commit            0x00000001027c2af3 0x1027a5000 + 121587
13  ar.com.adband.Commit            0x00000001027ae5f4 0x1027a5000 + 38388
14  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8785d562 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
15  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c8087a2 _pthread_start + 327
16  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c7f51e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff855ca6c2 semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff82145486 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 241
2   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff84339e1f xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 127
3   com.apple.SystemConfiguration   0x00007fff845229e5 __SCNetworkReachabilityServer_targetRemove + 108
4   com.apple.SystemConfiguration   0x00007fff844f5cbe __SCNetworkReachabilityDeallocate + 82
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8755c3df CFRelease + 511
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff821420b6 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff821431fa _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 304
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c80ad0b _pthread_wqthread + 404
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c7f51d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 7:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff82aa8711 objc_autoreleasePoolPush + 1
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff82143125 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 91
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c80ad0b _pthread_wqthread + 404
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c7f51d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff855cc6d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c80af4c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c80ad13 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c7f51d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff855ca686 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff855c9c42 mach_msg + 70
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87583233 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87588916 __CFRunLoopRun + 1078
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff875880e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87596dd1 CFRunLoopRun + 97
6   ar.com.adband.Commit            0x00000001027c20a5 0x1027a5000 + 118949
7   ar.com.adband.Commit            0x00000001027c2af3 0x1027a5000 + 121587
8   ar.com.adband.Commit            0x00000001027b5747 0x1027a5000 + 67399
9   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8785d562 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c8087a2 _pthread_start + 327
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c7f51e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 5 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
rax: 0x3000000000000000  rbx: 0x00000001061c9d30  rcx: 0x3000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
rdi: 0x00007fd3148276d0  rsi: 0x00007fff72e2d600  rbp: 0x00000001061c9d00  rsp: 0x00000001061c9cb8
r8: 0x00007fd3148276d0   r9: 0x00000000128ec648  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x00000000128ec648
r12: 0x0000000000000001  r13: 0x000000000000000d  r14: 0x00007fd3148240c0  r15: 0x00007fd3148276d0
rip: 0x00007fff82aa6750  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x0000000100502520
Logical CPU: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CFRelease failed, so it's very likely that an object was attempted to free that already is freed. See if you can find an execution path that might lead to a double release of an object there.

Comment: Hi Mike, a symbolication of the crash log does the trick. I just run atos on a terminal, and actually found the issue in one method with a uninitialized object. Many thanks.